# ImageMagick installed, but not working

Tags: php, imagemagick, php-extension

I'm an ImageMagick noob, so bear that in mind.

My host says ImageMagick is installed, and they're right. convert -version returns the version and everything when SSH'd into the server. But I can't get it to actually work.

I have tried using MagickWand and Imagick, but both are not installed because I get the `class 'Imagick' not found` error or similar. But even when I try:

```
$input = "image.jpg";
$output = "image2.jpg";
$convert = "/usr/local/bin/convert";
$command = "$convert $input $output";
exec($command, $return);
```

No image is created. Any ideas? Can I install Imagick or MagickWand? I don't have great privileges with my host, so I figure that is not an option. What am I doing wrong?

Disclaimer: I'm off to bed soon, so if I don't reply to any answers until later, that's why. If I do get an answer that solves the problem, I will definitely accept it.

Comment: Is your php code running in the correct directory, with the correct privileges?  For the former, try using full path names for `$input` and `$output`, e.g., `$input = "/home/blah/image.jpg"; $output = "/home/blah/image2.jpg;"`.  For the latter, try using a world-writable directory such as `/tmp`.  (These are intended to diagnose the problem; they aren't necessarily the right solution.)

Comment: what does a `print_r($return)` say? are there any hints regarding missing files / wrong permissions?

Comment: Ok, I fixed the path, and now the above code works, but if I add -resize 100x100 to it, it breaks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never really figured this one out. I ended up switching hosts because my host was being problematic and unhelpful.